# Meteor email all recipients were rejected

Tags: meteor

This Meteor server code uses email 1.0.12 package to send email.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  smtp = {
    username: 'some@gmail.com',
    password: 'myPassword',
    incomingServer: 'pop.someCompany.com',
    incomingPort: '110',
    outgoingServer: 'smtp.someCompany.com',
    outgoingPort: '587'
  };

  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.outgoingServer) + ':' + smtp.outgoingPort;
});
```

But the terminal error shows

> RecipientError: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected

What steps to take to find the cause of this problem in order to fix it? Thanks.

**edit**
The instructions from my web hosting company are:

1. Incoming email server: pop.companyName.com
2. Outgoing email server: smtp.companyName.com
3. Username: full mailbox name.
4. Password: mailbox password.
5. Incoming mail port: Port 110.
6. Outgoing mail port: Port 25 or Port 587.
7. Outgoing Server Authentication: Required.
8. Please make sure that you uncheck the option SSL for the incoming and outgoing mail servers.

Comment: [@Fred J](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5047454/fred-j). can you check your SMTP logs (again) and see if it is receiving the send request, or if it's failing before even reaching the server?